# How do I edit multiple features at one time?

Tags: qgis, editing, features, overlay

In my case, there are about 30 overlaid features. How do I select all and edit them at one time? I want to reshape the features, mainly using the node tool to reshape a straight line into a (fake) curve one.

Comment: Never seen an out of the box tool for this.

Comment: so the only method for me is to edit them one by one?

Comment: Yes or you could also just edit one of them, delete the rest and then copy - paste the new 29 times. This will give to the geometries. But you will have to edit the attributes manually to the values of the old line attributes that was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in modern QGIS if you use the Vertex Editor.

To move existing vertices, select them by dragging a rectangle mouse selection over them, then move them.

To introduce new vertices, select all lines that you want to edit, then use the vertex editor's "insert node in the middle of this line segment" feature. This node will be added to all the lines that are selected.

Note: At least currently your layer CRS and project CRS must match or it will silently not work. This issue is tracked at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51245

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to define how the co-located features should relate to each other in space.  That is their *topological* relationship in terms of their geometric construction. In ESRI software this is called a topology.

I don't think any of the open source projects have this ability yet (I would love to know if they do!).

You can work around these type of problems by constructing temporary features and then using batch geo-processing to clip/intersect the features you want to reshape.

Comment: in GRASS 7 you do have topology tools

Comment: @lllisa I'm not entirely clear on what your data currently looks like (a screenshot would help), but it does sound like topological editing is what you're looking for as kingmi mentions. QGIS does appear to have *some* kind of implementation for this per the [help docs](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html), and as radouxju mentions [GRASS layers](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html#grass-digitizing) approach it from a slightly different manner.