# How to edit geometry of multiple layers simultaneously in QGIS 3?

Tags: layers, geometry, editing, qgis-3, snapping

I have several line layers (route, pipes, cables) that share the same geometry and would like to edit them simultaneously.

Is there a way to easily snap the geometry of the pipes and cables layers to the route layer so that I can simply change the geometry of the route layer and don't have to repeat all changes on the other two layers as well?

To clarify, I plan a fibreglass route and have three layers. The first one describes the route that I have to take to pass all homes that have to be connected. The second one contains the pipes in which the cables lie and the third layer is the cable layer. So all features on those layers have to have the same geometry. Once I change the pathway of the route layer, I have to apply the same changes to the other two layers to ensure that they are still aligned with the route layer.
I'm not sure whether I understand your comments correctly, but I use the basic editing tools in QGIS 3.

Comment: which tool are you using?

Comment: Yes there is, depending on what tool you are using.

Comment: @IanTurton or Fjellrev, I clarified my specific problem (hopefully enough to make myself understood). Do you have good advice for me?

Answer (score 11):

(QGIS 3.4.1) Make sure all layers you want to edit have editing toggled on.

[image: all layers editable]

Using the vertex tool in the digitizing toolbar, ensuring the option for 'All layers' is selected from the dropdown next to the tool.

[image: vertex tool all layers]

Select nodes by dragging a box round it (rather than clicking it directly). They should turn blue.

[image]

Then click on a blue node to pick it up and move it. The selected vertices from all other editable layers will be moved relative to the one you picked up.

[image]

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks a lot! It's an embarrassingly easy solution, but I'm slowly getting used to have that experience working with GIS :D I just tried it and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi Fabian, very glad to help. If you are happy with my solution, could you mark it as correct so the question is closed. Many thanks!

Comment: And for introducing new nodes "within" the lines, one can select the lines beforehand, then use the vertex editor: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/470594/51035