# Moving elements together from two different layers

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins

How can I move elements together from two different layers?

I have to move element which consist of three separate elements on three separate layers. I attach a screenshot below. So is it possible? Maybe is any plugins which allows this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: You definitely should add more information about the context and use case as there might be different ways to achieve that. Adding a screenshot and (even better!) share your data with project file would help a lot to understand what you're looking for as well as providing an answer that works for your individual use case.

Comment: Copy from one layer, paste into the other, or use  `merge vector layers`. Also, don't expect to be able to create delivery paths for WTG-construction using QGIS. You need to use CAD for that.

Comment: See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/302600/128665) for moving features using the Vertex Tool across multiple layers. You should be able to drag a selection around all the nodes you wish to move.

Comment: @Erik I use CAD for that, but is waste of time. I hoped that i find any solution of this problem than merge layer or use other software

Comment: @Matt I mean moving elements like CAD, independently how many vertices you have

Comment: [This is not sufficient?](https://gyazo.com/c18bb85659eb88d4749f9248f449a787)

Comment: Sorry Matt my mistake. This solution is great :), thanks