# Shifting point where two lines meet in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, digitizing

I am trying to digitize a road network in QGIS 3.10.12. After tracing two lines, I want to shift the point where both lines meet a bit sideways with the node tool. However, only one point from one of the line moves when I try to shift it in QGIS 3.

In QGIS 2.18 I am able to move the node where both lines join. I have snapping enabled for the layer.

How can I shift the point where the two lines meet in QGIS 3?

Below is the image of the lines in QGIS 3:

[image]

The image below is performing same operation in QGIS 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the vertices by dragging a box around, instead of just clicking, they will turn blue. You can then click on them to move them together.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The relative movement applies for any vertices, whether they intersect or not. [Even in different layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/302600/128665), as long as the layers are editable.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was trying to do.